# Can i specify the site id to the path variable in a template?

Tags: templates, multi-site-manager, path

I.e., something like what embed does, `<a href="{default_site:path='group/template'}">`.

Comment: This question isn't making much sense. Can you expand on your question to detail exactly what you are trying to do? It would help to also know what you've tried... What you want the final URL to look like...

Comment: Also, I moved your code into the question... to format code, click on the {} icon in the WYSIWYG toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if you can use the path variable to automate linking to other sites in your MSM install? If so then I think the answer is no.  You could always create global variables to avoid manually typing the host information if you wanted.